# why i am getting error in recyclerView.layoutmanager=linearlayout

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

[here's my code ][1]

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoq`val](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoq%60val) recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
recyclerView.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this)
`xi.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to infer the correct type for the `findViewById` method, otherwise the `recyclerview` variable will be a generic `View` and not a `RecyclerView`

```
val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
```